# Существует ли программа, которая считает сложность алгоритмов?

Tags: time-complexity

Т.е. я вставляю в нее код, и она возвращает его сложность.

Comment: Чудес не бывает. нет такой. Потому что один и тот же код для различных вводных может работать по разной сложности. А сложность в общем случае подсчитать не самая простая задача. Это наглядно можно посмотреть на базах данных. Казалось бы что можно подсчитать актуальный план точно зарание но можно только приблизительный

Comment: а потом приходит clang, который в некоторых случаях умеет линейную сложность преобразовывать в константную. Поэтому, такая программа называется "мозг".